# Reading multiple Text files

Tags: c#, file, text

Just a question, I'am using c# mvc for a project and I have this requirement of getting several text files from a particular path (network path to be precised - eg: \10.0.0.1\SharedFolder). Now, each text files has different text formats and what I have to do is to get any existing files from that path folder and create a single text file for all the text files.

1. Is it possible to used a network path (the path was specified through user input) using a web application to access files?
2. If yes, what would you suggest?

I was already looking at the option of using "Browse Folder" button, however, I wasn't getting any progress on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the files located on the server or client?

Comment: First you need a user account with access to the file. Then you need to specify (in IIS) that the mvc application run as this user. Then, you need to enable impersonation in your web.config file in order for the application to actually access the file as that user.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it =>

Iterate through each file in the directory using the .net Directory class.

For each file:
Use the Textreaderclass to read each line
Use the Textwriter class to write each line to your designated file

Let me know if you still can't figure it out!

Comment: To be a bit more specific, use Directory.GetFiles to get each file in your path,
then, for each file, use TextReader.ReadLine to read each line in the file and write it to your file using TextReader.WriteLine

Comment: ow I see, thanks! I must have missed that one. I don't actually have a problem about reading the files. Getting the files is my problem. Still, I have another question, as I have mentioned, an output file should be created after reading the text files, could I write this file to the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can,

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("C:\\Output.txt"))
{

//WRITE WHATEVER YOU WANT TO WRITE.

}
```

Just replace "C:\Output.txt" with the directory you want.

Hope this helps